# Arity exception in clojure

Tags: exception, clojure, arity

I have this piece of code.

```
(defn get-movie [name-movie contents]
 (loop [n (count contents) contents contents]
  (let [movie (first contents)]
   (if (= (:name (first contents)) name-movie)
    (movie)
    (recur (dec n) (rest contents))))))
```

I have sequence of maps ({:id, :name, :price} {} {}). I need to find the map with the :name as given by me (Matching movie). When I give

```
(get-movie "Interstellar" contents)
```

where contents is

```
({:id 10000 :name "Interstellar" :price 1}{:id 10001 :name "Ouija" :price 2}).
```

I am getting the following exception. :

clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap
             AFn.java:437 clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity
              AFn.java:35 clojure.lang.AFn.invoke
C:\Users\Shalima\Documents\Textbooks\Functional Programming\Programs\Assignment5.clj:53 file.test/get-movie
C:\Users\Shalima\Documents\Textbooks\Functional Programming\Programs\Assignment5.clj:77 file.test/eval6219

I have been sitting with this for sometime now and still couldnt figure out what went wrong. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 7):

You are invoking movie (a map) like a function. Maps can be invoked with a key for lookup, but there is no 0-arity form. Presumably you just want to return the movie rather than invoke it (by surrounding it with parentheses).

```
(defn get-movie [name-movie contents]
 (loop [n (count contents) contents contents]
  (let [movie (first contents)]
   (if (= (:name (first contents)) name-movie)
    movie   ;; don't invoke
    (recur (dec n) (rest contents))))))
```

Not important to the question, but a simpler way to write this loop with destructuring would be:

```
(defn get-movie [name-movie contents]
 (loop [[{n :name :as movie} & movies] contents]
  (if (= n name-movie)
   movie   ;; don't invoke
   (recur movies))))
```

And if you wanted to move to higher order sequence functions and away from the lower level loop entirely you could do something like:

```
(defn get-movie [name-movie contents]
 (first (filter #(= name-movie (:name %)) contents)))
```

Comment: Oh yea.. How stupid of me... And thanks a lot... There are tons of ways to improve clojure code. I am still working my way up. Hope will reach there at some point.

Comment: Just one more question. What is the best way to decode the exception stack. It does not give the line of code and how do we figure it out where and what went wrong ?

Comment: The stack you listed had "C:\Users\Shalima\Documents\Textbooks\Functional Programming\Programs\Assignment5.clj:53" in it - is that not the line of offending code?

Comment: No.. it was the start of the function get-movie.

Comment: there are a couple bugs related to line number reporting (although at a glance this doesn't look like one of them). not sure.